# WooCommerce Add to cart not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently customizing my content-single-product.php template, and I need to add the simple_add_to_cart. It shows up fine and the quantity box seems to work, but when I click the add to cart button nothing happens.

Here is my full template code:

```html
<?php
 /**
  * woocommerce_before_single_product hook.
  *
  * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
  */
  do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

  if ( post_password_required() ) {
   echo get_the_password_form();
   return;
  }
?>
<div class="product_wrap">
 <div class="product_image_wrap">
  <div class="thumbnails navigator-2">
   <?php
   global $product;
  $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
 foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id )
 {
   //echo Image instead of URL
   echo '<div class="slider_thumb">' . wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail') . '</div>';
 }
 ?>
  </div>
  <div class="main_image">
   <div class="product-slider prod-nav">
    <?php
   global $product;
   $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

  foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id )
  {
   //echo Image instead of URL
   echo '<div class="prod_img">' . wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full') . '</div>';
  }
  ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="product_content_wrap">
  <div itemscope itemtype="<?php echo woocommerce_get_product_schema(); ?>" id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

   <div class="summary entry-summary">
    <h3><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'comic_series', true ); ?></h3>
    <h1><?php woocommerce_template_single_title(); ?></h1>
    <h2><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'author_info', true ); ?></h2>
    <div class="product_description">
     <?php woocommerce_product_description_tab(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="add_to_cart">
     <?php woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart(); ?>
    </div>
   </div><!-- .summary -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="product_details_wrap">
 <div class="product_details">
  <div class="details_content">
   <h4>Details</h4>
   <ul>
    <li><p><span>Published:</span> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'published', true ); ?></p></li>
    <li><p><span>Writer:</span> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'writer', true ); ?></p></li>
    <li><p><span>Penciller:</span> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'penciller', true ); ?></p></li>
    <li><p><span>Cover Artist:</span> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cover_artist', true ); ?></p></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li><p><span>Format:</span> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'format', true ); ?></p></li>
    <li><p><span>Price:</span> <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></p></li>
    <li><p><span>UPC:</span> <?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?></p></li>
    <li><p><span>FOC Date:</span> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'foc_date', true ); ?></p></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Obviously I am loading a few custom fields for the product, but it is a simple product. I am owndering what I may be missing here...

Comment: Looks like I did miss that so I added it. Unfortunatly it did not have an effect. I even actually went so far as to copy/paste the full original template into my file...and even it did not work. I feel like I am missing something fundamental here, but not certain what it could be...almost like the form action is not working....

Comment: May be you should better NOT edit `content-single-product.php` template directly for most of all, but the hooked templates (or child templates). Then you can unset or reorder them with `remove_action()` and `add_action()` functions playing with the priorities of `add_action()` function. Then you can keep only the product details in `content-single-product.php template`. This way you discrease the risk of missing something essential.

Comment: I wish that I could, but this site really calls for this. I actually renamed my files, and went back to all original woo themes and it STILL didnt work. I also removed all of my custom Woo functions out of the functions.php file and no luck! I am thinking I may have a conflict elsewhere...still digging. Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out its a conflict with Advanced Custom Fields! I am going to research this a little more, and possibly post a new question. Pretty crazy!

Comment: You should better delete this as it's not an answer (Just an advise)… Remember that the best way is first to use the woocommerce hooks and methods. I think that you don't really need ACF to do what you want.